# Magento Bundled Price Not showing up in listing pages

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2 and certainly I observed that the bundle pricing is not showing up in the listing pages of product.

Is there any quick fix for it? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: we don't like guessing what can be wrong. Can you please provide an example, some code, the error message, what is going wrong, why you think that happends and what you've done to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I will just toss a big fat guess at it and say that if you are adding a block that is custom, you may need to add the Price action hook like so:

```
<reference name="content">
   <block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page">
      <action method="addPriceBlockType">
        <type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
      </action>
   </block>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found this solution to the problem of bundle pricing not displaying properly in category pages: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/224677/.

I hope it will help.

Thanks, 
C

Comment: Please paraphrase the linked answer here.

Comment: link is no longer valid